# Conditional statement to assign new row character based on different column

Tags: r, for-loop, conditional-statements

I am a new R user trying to expedite the ways in which I fill in missing data/unknowns.

I have a dataframe with incomplete data on plant quadrats surveyed this year. I would like to write a conditional statement to quickly fill in NA's on other descriptive column (ie floristic_qulaity, habitat, etc.) based on a the latin name.

For example, maybe a a for loop for many different species in which I can fill NA information?

for df$latin_name == "Cyperus ovatus" {df$status = "Native"}

for df$latin_name == "Paspalum notatum" {df$floristic_quality = "Noxious"}

etc.

Thank you!

Comment: Please share a minimal reproducible example of your data: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: If you have a reference data frame with the complete information you'd use to fill in missing information on a new data frame then a flavor of `join` is a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure if I completely understand your problem, but here's a tidyverse solution:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  mutate(status            = if_else(latin_name == "Cyperus ovatus", "Native", status),
         floristic_quality = if_else(latin_name == "Paspalum notatum", "Noxious", floristic_quality))
```